# peopleManager.getMyProperties in C# gives 403 error

Tags: 2013, userprofilemanager

I need to read the properties for the current sharepoint user in a C# method, using CSOM.

I've tried using an example from
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/490/how-to-get-the-current-users-properties-using-csom-in-sharep.aspx

But there's a 403 error during ExecuteQuery()

```
     ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL); 
            PeopleManager peopleManager = new PeopleManager(clientContext);  
            PersonProperties personProperties = peopleManager.GetMyProperties();  
            clientContext.Load(personProperties, p => p.AccountName, p => p.Email, p => p.DisplayName);  
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Why am I forbidden from accessing the user properties? 
Does it require some special authentication?

the thing is that I am able to call the getmyproperties service in javascript by a regular get request, so I figured that no authorization was required to access them

```
siteUrl + "/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getmyproperties"
```

Comment: Seems like I get a 403 error from executing ANY query.  Even something like this

using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
            {  Web web = clientContext.Web;
                clientContext.Load(web);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the code was running in the app pool which was not trusted to access the site.